# Cloudflare causes slow requests

Tags: performance, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare as a proxy to protect against attacks on my site, but when i turn it on, suddenly some css requests can take up to 15 seconds (files that weigh 500B).

what could be causing this issue? the irony is that cloudflare should decrease response time...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That could be tied to your SSL settings.  You may want to review:

[Error 522: Connection timed out](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out)

or you could try loading your assets relative to the protocol:

[Why are my images/css/js files missing when I load my page over HTTPS?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204151588-Why-are-my-images-css-js-files-missing-when-I-load-my-page-over-HTTPS-)

If neither of those articles offer a solution, you can also try [community.cloudflare.com](http://community.cloudflare.com) or submit a ticket to support[@]cloudflare[.]com.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i switched to a different service... it solved the issue

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you change your mind you can always email support for additional guidance.

Comment: @WalksAway, to which one? any recommendation?

Comment: @WalksAway, user name checks out